# Using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor to updateRow gives RuntimeError: row contains bad value?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.6, runtimeerror

I have a fishnet grid (polygon SHP), and all the little fishnets have a "Zone_ID." There are generally several dozen to a few hundred fishnet polys associated with each Zone_ID. I'm trying to number each fishnet poly based on the zone. Screenshot below is a simple example of what I'm tring to code. (Fishnets have already been intersected with zones, and the topology is correct.)

[image]

```
arcpy.AddField_management("MyFishnet_wZones.shp", "Fishnet_ID", "SHORT", field_is_nullable = "NULLABLE")

nPolygons = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("MyZones.shp").getOutput(0)) # length nPolygons is the total number of zones

for n in range(0, nPolygons):
    counter = 1
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("MyFishnet_wZones.shp", ["Zone_ID", "Fishnet_ID"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            while row[0] == n + 1: # because Zone_ID starts at 1, not 0
                row[1] = counter
                cursor.updateRow(row)
                counter += 1
```

And here's the error:

```
    File "", line X, in <module>
        cursor.updateRow(row)
RuntimeError: The row contains a bad value.
```

Comment: What is `fieldName1` set to?  That should be in your [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).

Comment: For various causes of bad values see https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22row+contains+a+bad+value%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it--putting in a SQL statement worked

```
for n in range(0, nPolygons):
    counter = 1
    sql = '"Zone_ID"= ' + str(n + 1)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("MyFishnet_wZones.shp", ["Zone_ID", "Fishnet_ID"], sql) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[1] = counter
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are being told that you are providing a bad value when the cursor encounters a NULL value in your `Zone_ID` or other field.  However, it may also be that the value you are trying to push into a text field is too long for that field.

I suspect that [your answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296607/115) of restricting the cursor to a subset of rows using a where_clause avoids the error by no longer needing to access the offending row.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of a dictionary you can get your desired results with a single cursor.

```
di = {}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("MyFishnet_wZones.shp", ["Zone_ID", "Fishnet_ID"]) as curs:
    for zone, fishnet in curs:
        try: lastVal = di [zone]
        except KeyError: lastVal = 1
        row = (zone, lastVal)
        curs.updateRow (row)
        lastVal += 1
        di [zone] = lastVal
```